# Exposed DependencyProperty in UserControl but cannot bind

Tags: c#, wpf, image, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have searched for a solution to this in the forum. There are several similar questions and solutions but I cannot really understand them. Pardon me for asking again... :P

Let me explain my setup... I have a UserControl which is developed as a separate dll from the Main application. Within this rather complicated UserControl, I have several child controls. One of them is a Image. I declared a DependencyProperty at the UserControl code-behind to expose the Source property of the Image.

```
public static DependencyProperty MyImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(MyUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

public ImageSource MyImageSource
{
   get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(MyImageSourceProperty); }
   set { SetValue(MyImageSourceProperty, value); }
}
```

Then in my Main Application, I placed the UserControl in my MainWindow and rigged it up as such...

```
   <controls:MyUserControl Name="MyControl" MyImageSource={Binding MySource}/>
```

MySource is declared in my MainWindow's ViewModel.

```
    public string MySource
   {
      get { return this.mySource; }
      set { if (value == mySource) 
               return;
            this.mySource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MySource");
          }
   }
```

Basically, the program is supposed to function as such :
1) User clicks on a Button in the MainWindow.
2) An openFileDialog pops up and he selects an image file to load.
3) Once he confirms the selection, the image should load up in MyUserControl's Image control. I.e. MySource is updated, which triggers a whole ripple of events resulting in the Image's Source property being updated.

The compilation went without errors. But when I tried to execute the program, and selects the image I want to load, image does not show at all...

Hope someone can enlighten me on this. Really banging against walls for hours trying to figure out what went wrong.... Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: You should have binding error in the visual studio console which can help you to solve your problem

Comment: Have specified the form's class as the data source for the form? Otherwise: How should she user control know which object contains the `MySource` property? For example, you could do that in the constructor.

Comment: You can't bind the ImageSource propety directly to string.
See [Binding Image.Source to String in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573912/binding-image-source-to-string-in-wpf) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to the constructor:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

This tells the form that it is its own data context. Otherwise the user control doesn't know which object "hosts" the `MySource` property.