# WPF Image to string and string to image

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have a data driven application and one of the entities is supposed to have an image attached to it. Now, since I'm putting the images in a sub-folder of my project directory I don't need to serialize the actual image to the binary file, just the path to it. The image is selected from a `ListBox` that contains thumbnails and should be displayed on an image panel in another dialogue (when the appropriate entity is selected)

I can't seem to extract the path from the actual `Image`. The `ListBox` is bound to an object of the type `Image` in the `ViewModel` and from there I should be extracting the path and placing it in the constructor of the object.

The other thing I need is to access the image using the path, in another dialogue. Basically, in my table of entities I have a details panel that shows all the attributes of the selected entity, but how would I go about displaying the image if I only have it's path?

Comment: Posting the code would be helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573912/binding-image-source-to-string-in-wpf

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/gridview/using-a-converter-for-string-to-image.aspx

Comment: As I can see you have to handle the couple Image/path. Why don't you make a simple object containing that information and work with `Converters`? it may be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved my issue using `BitmapImage` instead of `Image`. I accessed the absolute path, via the `UriSource` property, after which I split the string, using `\` as the splitter argument.

I then simply accessed the last element of the array of strings formed by the split method to save the name of the image. After that it was only a matter of creating a new Bitmap image with the given `Uri` using the following parameter:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + App.MyPictureFolder + MyPictureName
```

Where MyPictureFolder is a static string variable whichc contains the name of the appropriate folder. Might not be the best method, but it works well enough for me.