# Binding Custom ImageSource Path by using MVVM

Tags: c#, windows, mvvm, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am developing a shopping catalog and I am a noob in MVVM so please help me, is it possible to bind a custom path in `ImageSource`? here is my basic code:

The view ?

```
public class CakeData
        {
            public string Cakename { get; set; }
            public ImageSource _imageSource { get; set; }

        }
```

And the DataSource:

```
 public List<CakeData> _cakeData;
        public List<CakeData> CakeData
        {
            get
            {
                return _cakeData;
            }
            set
            {

                SetProperty(ref _cakeData, value);
            }
        }



    public CakeDataSource()
            {
                string commander = "select * from tblCakes where caketype='Cakes'";

                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
                MySqlCommand ds = new MySqlCommand(commander, connection);
                connection.Open();
                MySqlDataReader dt = ds.ExecuteReader();
                CakeData = new List<CakeData>();
                while (dt.Read())
                {
                    CakeName = dt.GetString("cakename");
                    ImageSource img= new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"D:\hunterZ Documents\Systems\UnderDevelopment\SweetApp\SweetApp\bin\Debug\AppX\cakeimages\keiki1.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
            CakeData.Add(new CakeData { Cakename = wew, _imageSource = img});//is it possible to apply the custom path like D:/pictures/blackforest.png?
                }
                dt.Close();

            }
```

and here's my xaml code:

```
<page.DataContext>
<vm:CakeDataSource/>
</page.DataContext>

....
     <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="397" Height="248">
                                <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>//this is the picture that i want to modify`
                                </Border>
                                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="CakeName"  Text="{Binding Cakename}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>

                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: i've tried to bind it directly but blank image appears. i think images referenced in the solution can be used (example: Assets)

Comment: Show us your xaml file, please. Anyway, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2574144/3257426 . I also assume, you're binding to the Property without a ValueConverter? Thus, you're type is wrong - ImageSource shouldn't be `string`, it should be of type `ImageSource`.

Comment: so meaning i will declare the ImageSource variable into "ImageSource" of image?

Comment: Show us your XAML code please..

Comment: there i've included the xaml code for the image that i wanted to modify. please keep the answer simple as possible as i am a noob in mvvm. i want to understand them clearly step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i've posted in the comments, you should change your type of your property called `ImageSource` to the *type* `ImageSource` aswell:

```
public ImageSource ImageSource { get; set; }
```

Then, setup your Image - for example in the ctor of your ViewModel:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"path/to/your/image.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

The path has to be relative to your application directory, otherwise use an absolute path like `@"C:\Path\To\My\Image.jpg"` and set the `UriKind` to `Absolute`.

Note that if you're setting the ImageSource not in the ctor, your ViewModel needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` for your property.

**Edit:** Check your binding! Your Viewmodel also provides a property called `ImageSource`, your view is binding to `ImagePath`

Comment: thanks, another question how am i going to add my list for example i use this to add CakeData to a list:   CakeData.Add(new CakeData { Cakename = Name, ImagePath = "image/path/here.jpg"}); is this correct?      ..ImageSource img= new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:/path/to/picture/here.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
  CakeData.Add(new CakeData { Cakename = wew, ImagePath = img});

Comment: CakeData has no property ImagePath in your example. If you mean ImageSource, i've instructed you to get rid of the string property, change it to ImageSource!

Comment: i've edited my code please check if im right in executing it.

Comment: You are providing an **absolute** path (As you can see your path starts with "D:\"..), and you are using `UriKind.Relative`. Use `UriKind.Absolute`