# WPF C# Cannot get image to show via source binding

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I cannot get an image to show on my window.

I want to bind the source, but the problem appears to run deeper.

I have these 2 lines:

```
<Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding EnemyImagePath}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding EnemyImagePath}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
```

The textbox is showing exactly what I would expect it to. (/RSClick;component/Images/Enemies/001.png). However, image isnt showing at all.

I went ahead and changed the image in XAML to this:

```
<Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Source="Images/Enemies/001.png" />
```

and as soon as I did, the image shows up. (I selected the source from the properties panel to get this). I have set the image to Embedded resource and copy always - And I have double checked that it is being created, with the correct folder structure, in the BIN folder for my project.

When I run the program, with the image set statically as above, the image wont show when the program runs. It will, however, show itself normally within the designer...

Thanks :)

Comment: The type of the `Source` property is `ImageSource`, not `string`. Being able to enter a path in XAML is a convenient shortcut, but if you want to use binding you'll have to load the image yourself and expose it via a property to the binding system.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2574082/1997232) too.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet That is not true, String or Uri or byte[] property value are automatically converted by a built-in type converter (ImageSourceConverter), even in WPF data binding. This feature is not limited to XAML, because it is not provided by the XAML Parser.

Answer (score 0):

The path you provide is called a [Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx).
When using Pack URIs, you have to set the *Build Action* as `Resource`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    <Image Source="{Binding ImgPath}" />

public string ImgPath
{
    get { return "pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Images/image_to_use.png"; }
}
```